# Why isn't NuGet manager showing for one SLN in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

This just happened with one of my SLN's which is made up of several projects.

In Visual Studio 2022 (C# .NET) I'm getting a bunch of MSB4018 Errors and all of my NuGet dependencies have warning icons. If I try to launch the NuGet package manager, nothing happens.

Other solutions on the same machine do not have this problem. The NuGet manager appears without issue on them.

This same SLN on a different PC has no problems.  Thus the problem relates to one SLN on one of my development machines.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Nuke your local machine's NuGet cache, and everything in all the solution's `bin` and `obj` directories - especially the `project.assets.json` files.

Comment: Just tried that.  Still no joy.